# Error while connecting Kafka over local wifi network created using ESP8266

Tags: apache-kafka

**Context**: I am trying to connect Kafka on a local WiFi network that I created using ESP8266 devices and SoftAP.

**What I am Trying to Achieve**: I want devices (Laptops connected with ESP8266 SoftAP) to send and receive messages between each other using Kafka on a local WiFi network that is not connected to the internet.

**Problem**: One of the devices in the network is a Raspberry Pi and I am running Kafka over it. The error I am getting is

```
[2022-05-09 14:54:43,622] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Error connecting to node :192.168.4.2:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: :192.168.4.2: invalid IPv6 address
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1345)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:984)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:64)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:291)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:245)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
[2022-05-09 14:54:43,622] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

some of the config/server.properties are as follow:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:0.0.0.0:9092 
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:192.168.4.2:9092 
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

Comment: Please show your code. The error suggests you have colons as part of the bootstrap address

Comment: Hi! I am working on console at the moment and I am using simple commands such as kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.4.1:9092 --list

However, some of the config/server.properties are as follow: 
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:192.168.4.2:9092
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

Comment: Remove the extra colon after the slashes in both  those listener settings and restart the broker

Comment: I gave one external IP to the server and it started to work. The external IP is completely made up. I don't know why it worked like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. All I said was to remove a character in the settings, not give a different address

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it's trying to use `:192.168.4.2` as an IPv6 host, rather than an IPv4 address.

You need to remove the leading colon of that IP in your two listeners settings.

Kafka might be too much for a Raspberry Pi, depending on the model. Mosquito MQTT or NATS would be more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider trying our [Scramjet Transform Hub](https://github.com/scramjetorg/transform-hub) as an alternative.

Normally it's used with the Platform to connect distributed locations together, but if you simply install it on a Pi and make http connections to the `/api/v1/topic/*` endpoints you can stream messages between the controllers by just pushing the data via a long lived `POST` request and receive with a long lived `GET` even with just binary data (use appropriate content-type).

To install it you'll need node.js on the Pi and then simply:

```bash
npm i @scramjet/sth
sth --help # this will get you the command line options
```

You could also write a js or python program (long-lived cloud function) like this to make sure you get proper validation:

```js
module.exports = function* (input) {
    for await (const chunk of input) {
        if (!valid(chunk)) continue;
        yield doSomeMapping(chunk);
    }
}
```

and send it over with the command:

```bash
si seq deploy . --input-topic esp.input --output-topic esp.output
```

We have some code samples that deploy Project Zephyr based code to ESP32/RPi2040 from a program running in the Hub - although I think your use case is a bit different.

Here's some more links:

- [Pi Os with the Hub installed as a service](https://github.com/scramjetorg/pi-gen)
- [The docs on STH](https://docs.scramjet.org/platform/transform-hub/)

I hope this is helpful. :)

Disclamer: I am the co-author. :)